# HTML and register mark in Outlook 2010/2007

Tags: html

Has anyone found the magic coding snippet to get a good register mark across the board in email readers? Not browser-based email like google, hotmail as they use the browser engine to render but actual email programs: Entourage/Outlook/.

We use old-school html and only css for styling fonts not structure of course. And we don't send big images so we're doing it right for across the board but the only stickler now is getting the register character superscripted and legible.

This is close but not legible Outlook:

```
<sup style="font-size: 0.6em; line-height: 0; 
*vertical-align: baseline; *position: relative; *bottom: 4px;">&reg;</sup>
```

Comment: What do you mean "not legible"? Not visible, visible but not recognisable as a registry mark, shows up as something else? (Sorry, no Outlook here I can test with.)

Comment: Outlook uses the MS Word engine to render Email - so save your file, open it up in WORD for testing purposes.

Comment: Word is an old html rendering machine. The updates to the Word rendering engine were neglible. It's not advisable to use word to test emails that are going out to hundreds of thousands of people who use Entourage/Outlook/GMail etc, etc... because you'll only see those who use Outlook 2007 or 2010.

Comment: &Mr Lister- It's fuzzy, appears to be cut-off and not legible as a "R"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<font class=reg>®</font>
```

with e.g.

```
<style>
.reg { font-family: Verdana, Arial; }
</style>
```

The REGISTERED SIGN ® has very varying implementations in fonts. I you don’t like it in the font selected, then changing font is probably a lesser evil than trying to style the character—I mean styling that changes the glyph size or vertical placement. One reason to this is that you cannot change the stroke width: by reducing size, you would reduce the stroke width, possibly beyond recognizability.

There’s usually no point in making ® superscripted or small-size. It’s a typographic design decision, and if the font designer decided to make it a small superscript, fine, use that if you agree with the decision. If the font designer decided otherwise, then, if he did his work well, the character does not behave well when superscripted.

Comment: Yes, I agree with all you said. Personally, I'd rather have it small and on the baseline instead of as large as a character next to it - which I've seen before but the design aspect is the issue. Thanks for the comment...ps... what size was your base?

Comment: @Ibreau, sorry I don’t understand the question about the base. But regarding the designs, most fonts have the “R” in “®” near the baseline of text and with a height near to the x-height of the font. The minority design is raised and often rather small size. Apart from designing a new font, I don’t see what you could do. For example, if you take Arial ® and reduce the size, the strokes would get rather thin.